# Reading the first key of a yaml file

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning python and at the same time, I'm creating a simple flask blog the reads markdown files.
These files are mapped with a yaml file that has the title, the date and the slug.

The yaml file that maps all posts [posts.yaml]:

```
---
title: title of the last posts
date: 10/12/2012
slug: title-of-the-last-post
type: post
---
title: title of another posts
date: 10/11/2012
slug: title-of-another-post
type: post
---
title: title of a posts
date: 10/10/2012
slug: title-of-a-post
type: post
---
```

The example of a markdown post, where the file name matches the slug in the yaml file [title-of-a-post.md]:

```
title: title of a posts
date: 10/10/2012
slug: title-of-a-post

The text of the post...
```

I already can read and present the markdown file. I can generate the links from the yaml file, what I'm fight right now is after reading the yaml file, supposing I have 10 posts, how can I show only the last 5 posts/links?

I'm using a FOR IN loop to show all links, but I only want to show the last 5.
How can I accomplish that?

```
{% for doc in docs if doc.type == 'post' %}
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('page', file = doc.slug) }}">{{ doc.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

The other problem is getting the last post (by date) to show in the fist page. This information should be returned from the yaml file.

At the top of the yaml file, I have the last post, so the posts are ordered by date descendant.

This is the flask file:

```
import os, codecs, yaml, markdown
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from flask import Flask, render_template, Markup, abort, redirect, url_for, request
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configuration

PAGES_DIR  = 'pages'
POSTS_FILE = 'posts.yaml'
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# Routes

@app.route('/')
def index():
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), app.config['POSTS_FILE']))
    data = open(path, 'r')
    docs = yaml.load_all(data)
    return render_template('home.html', docs=docs)


@app.route('/<file>')
def page(file):
    filename = secure_filename(file + '.md')
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), app.config['PAGES_DIR'], filename))

    try:
        f = codecs.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    except IOError: 
        return render_template('404.html'), 404

    text = markdown.Markdown(extensions = ['meta'])
    html = text.convert( f.read() )
    return render_template('pages.html', **locals())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: I'm not sure if your title "Reading the first key in YAML" is really a good description of your actual question. Your question seems to be related to how to use Jinja (although it appears that what you SHOULD be doing is creating/sorting the list of 5 elements in your view and then passing that list to Jinja to display).

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `Jinja2` (the default template library of Flask) documentation on [Loop Control](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/extensions/#loop-controls), built in [Filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#builtin-filters) and [Control Structures](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#list-of-control-structures).

Of interest to you is:

- <strike>[`reverse(seq)`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#reverse) function (if your posts are ordered date ascending).</strike> I see you mentioned date descending.
- [`loop.index` or `loop.index0`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#for) for getting the current loop count.
- [`first(seq)`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#first) for pulling the first item out of a sequence, of course there is also [`last(seq)`.](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#last)

And normal (awesome!) Python slicing syntax is available to you, eg

```
for doc in docs[:5]
    # Only loops over the first 5 items...
```

I see `posts.yaml` has a `type`, the loop will get a bit more complicated if you are mixing in non-'post' types. You might want to think about avoiding heavy sorting / filtering / logic in templates.

Hope that gets you on the right track.